# Testing Nuxtjs App with AVA and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, nuxt.js, ava

I'm creating a Nuxt app with TypeScript and want to unit test with AVA. However when I try to run a test I get:

> ✖ Couldn't find any files to test

I have `@nuxt/typescript-build` installed and added to my `nuxt.config.js`

Project structure (excluding stuff like package.json):

```
- components/
  - CardItem.vue
- test/
  - specs/
    -CardItem.spec.ts
  - ava.setup.js
- ava.config.cjs
- nuxt.config.js
- tsconfig.json
```

This is my `ava.config.cjs`:

```js
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    require: ['./test/ava.setup.js'],
    ignoredByWatcher: ['!**/*.{js,vue}'],
    babel: true,
    tap: false,
    verbose: false,
    color: true
  }
}
```

This is my `ava.setup.js`:

```js
require('browser-env')()
const hooks = require('require-extension-hooks')
const Vue = require('vue')

Vue.config.productionTip = false

window.Date = global.Date = Date

hooks('vue')
  .plugin('vue')
  .push()
hooks(['vue', 'js'])
  .exclude(({ filename }) => filename.match(/\/node_modules\//))
  .plugin('babel')
  .push()
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.asynciterable", "dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": ["@types/node", "@nuxt/types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

This is my `CardItem.spec.ts`:

```js
import test from 'ava'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import CardItem from '@/components/CardItem.vue'

test('renders it\'s graphic', async t => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(CardItem)

  t.fail()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/06-configuration.md), Ava does not look for typescript file extensions by default. Looks like you also need https://github.com/avajs/typescript, so I'd recommend following that README first.